# Exception during db mirroring failover to SQL Server 2022 from previous version

Tags: sql-server, database-migration, database-mirroring, sql-server-2022

To perform upgrade of production DB cluster from the current SQL Server 2014 to the new SQL Server 2022 without downtime, I use [DB Mirroring approach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/database-mirroring/upgrading-mirrored-instances):

Primary node - SQL Server 2014 Std (v12.0.6439.10, Build 9600)
Secondary node - SQL Server 2022 Enterprise (v16.0.1000.6, Build 20348)
Witness node - no.

During DB failover procedure (`ALTER DATABASE DBNameABC SET PARTNER FAILOVER`) to the secondary node, a new SQL server executes DB upgrade steps to the latest version and fails in the middle with the error "A ledger table cannot be created while database mirroring is enabled." See engine error log below.

As result, DB on the new server is stuck "In Recovery" mode and DB can't be accessed any longer.

```
2022-12-01 16:35:37.67 spid4s      The mirrored database "DBNameABC" is changing roles from "MIRROR" to "PRINCIPAL" because the mirroring session or availability group failed over due to failover from partner. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2022-12-01 16:35:37.68 spid16s     RBPEX::NotifyFileShutdown: Called for database ID: [10], file Id [0]
2022-12-01 16:35:37.68 spid16s     Starting up database 'DBNameABC'.
2022-12-01 16:35:37.68 spid16s     RemoveStaleDbEntries: Cleanup of stale DB entries called for database ID: [10]
2022-12-01 16:35:37.68 spid16s     RemoveStaleDbEntries: Cleanup of stale DB entries skipped because master db is not memory optimized. DbId: 10.
2022-12-01 16:35:37.70 spid16s     Parallel redo is started for database 'DBNameABC' with worker pool size [4].
2022-12-01 16:35:37.71 spid16s     5 transactions rolled forward in database 'DBNameABC' (10:0). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2022-12-01 16:35:37.72 spid16s     0 transactions rolled back in database 'DBNameABC' (10:0). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2022-12-01 16:35:37.72 spid16s     Parallel redo is shutdown for database 'DBNameABC' with worker pool size [4].
2022-12-01 16:35:37.72 spid16s     Converting database 'DBNameABC' from version 782 to the current version 957.
2022-12-01 16:35:37.72 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 782 to version 801.
2022-12-01 16:35:37.73 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 801 to version 802.
2022-12-01 16:35:37.73 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 802 to version 803.
2022-12-01 16:35:37.73 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 803 to version 804.
2022-12-01 16:35:37.74 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 804 to version 805.
2022-12-01 16:35:37.75 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 805 to version 806.
2022-12-01 16:35:37.76 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 806 to version 807.
2022-12-01 16:35:37.76 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 807 to version 808.
2022-12-01 16:35:37.77 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 808 to version 809.
2022-12-01 16:35:37.78 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 809 to version 810.
2022-12-01 16:35:37.79 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 810 to version 811.
2022-12-01 16:35:37.79 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 811 to version 812.
2022-12-01 16:35:37.80 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 812 to version 813.
2022-12-01 16:35:37.84 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 813 to version 814.
2022-12-01 16:35:37.84 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 814 to version 815.
2022-12-01 16:35:37.85 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 815 to version 816.
2022-12-01 16:35:37.86 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 816 to version 817.
2022-12-01 16:35:37.86 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 817 to version 818.
2022-12-01 16:35:37.87 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 818 to version 819.
2022-12-01 16:35:37.87 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 819 to version 820.
2022-12-01 16:35:37.88 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 820 to version 821.
2022-12-01 16:35:37.88 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 821 to version 822.
2022-12-01 16:35:37.88 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 822 to version 823.
2022-12-01 16:35:37.89 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 823 to version 824.
2022-12-01 16:35:37.89 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 824 to version 825.
2022-12-01 16:35:37.90 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 825 to version 826.
2022-12-01 16:35:37.90 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 826 to version 827.
2022-12-01 16:35:37.90 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 827 to version 828.
2022-12-01 16:35:37.91 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 828 to version 829.
2022-12-01 16:35:37.91 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 829 to version 830.
2022-12-01 16:35:37.91 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 830 to version 831.
2022-12-01 16:35:37.92 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 831 to version 832.
2022-12-01 16:35:37.92 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 832 to version 833.
2022-12-01 16:35:37.92 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 833 to version 834.
2022-12-01 16:35:37.93 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 834 to version 835.
2022-12-01 16:35:37.93 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 835 to version 836.
2022-12-01 16:35:37.93 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 836 to version 837.
2022-12-01 16:35:37.94 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 837 to version 838.
2022-12-01 16:35:37.94 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 838 to version 839.
2022-12-01 16:35:37.95 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 839 to version 840.
2022-12-01 16:35:37.95 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 840 to version 841.
2022-12-01 16:35:37.95 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 841 to version 842.
2022-12-01 16:35:37.96 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 842 to version 843.
2022-12-01 16:35:37.97 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 843 to version 844.
2022-12-01 16:35:37.97 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 844 to version 845.
2022-12-01 16:35:37.97 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 845 to version 846.
2022-12-01 16:35:37.98 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 846 to version 847.
2022-12-01 16:35:37.98 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 847 to version 848.
2022-12-01 16:35:37.98 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 848 to version 849.
2022-12-01 16:35:37.99 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 849 to version 850.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.00 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 850 to version 851.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.00 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 851 to version 852.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.01 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 852 to version 853.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.01 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 853 to version 854.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.01 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 854 to version 855.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.02 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 855 to version 856.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.03 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 856 to version 857.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.03 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 857 to version 858.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.03 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 858 to version 859.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.04 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 859 to version 860.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.04 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 860 to version 861.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.04 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 861 to version 862.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.05 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 862 to version 863.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.06 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 863 to version 864.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.06 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 864 to version 865.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.07 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 865 to version 866.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.07 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 866 to version 867.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.07 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 867 to version 868.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.08 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 868 to version 869.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.08 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 869 to version 875.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.09 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 875 to version 876.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.09 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 876 to version 877.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.10 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 877 to version 878.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.10 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 878 to version 879.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.11 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 879 to version 880.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.11 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 880 to version 881.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.12 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 881 to version 882.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.12 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 882 to version 883.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.13 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 883 to version 884.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.13 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 884 to version 885.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.13 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 885 to version 886.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.14 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 886 to version 887.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.14 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 887 to version 888.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.15 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 888 to version 889.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.15 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 889 to version 890.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.15 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 890 to version 891.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.16 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 891 to version 892.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.16 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 892 to version 893.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.17 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 893 to version 894.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.17 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 894 to version 895.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.18 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 895 to version 896.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.18 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 896 to version 897.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.18 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 897 to version 898.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.19 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 898 to version 899.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.19 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 899 to version 900.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.20 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 900 to version 901.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.21 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 901 to version 902.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.21 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 902 to version 903.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.22 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 903 to version 904.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.22 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 904 to version 905.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.22 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 905 to version 906.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.24 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 906 to version 907.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.24 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 907 to version 908.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.24 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 908 to version 909.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.25 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 909 to version 910.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.25 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 910 to version 911.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.25 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 911 to version 912.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.26 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 912 to version 913.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.27 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 913 to version 914.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.27 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 914 to version 915.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.28 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 915 to version 916.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.28 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 916 to version 917.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.29 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 917 to version 918.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.29 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 918 to version 919.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.29 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 919 to version 920.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.30 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 920 to version 921.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.31 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 921 to version 922.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.31 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 922 to version 923.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.32 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 923 to version 924.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.32 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 924 to version 925.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.33 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 925 to version 926.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.33 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 926 to version 927.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.34 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 927 to version 928.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.35 spid16s     Database 'DBNameABC' running the upgrade step from version 928 to version 929.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.35 spid16s     Error: 37526, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.35 spid16s     A ledger table cannot be created while database mirroring is enabled.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.35 spid16s     Error: 928, Severity: 20, State: 1.
2022-12-01 16:35:38.35 spid16s     During upgrade, database raised exception 3602, severity 25, state 51, address 00007FFAA33B3614. Use the exception number to determine the cause.
```

Other steps were made:

1. According to the Microsoft Data Migration Assistant tool - no compatibility issues were reported to upgrade db.
2. Procedure to restore DB to the new server from the backup file (without using db mirroring) and update DB Compatibility level to SQL Server 2022 (160) works fine. No issues. DB is operational in that case.

Any ideas?

Comment: I found the workaround.
All internal DB versions above 904 belong to SQL Server 2022.
As DB upgrade fails on v929, I decided to perform the upgrade in 2 phases: 
1) upgrade to SQL Server 2019 (v904) first via db mirroring
2) upgrade to SQL Server 2022 (v957) via AlwaysOn

Steps:
1) Setup DB Mirroring: node 1 - SQL v2014, node 2- SQL v2019
2)  DB Failover procedure. DB upgraded to v904 successfully
3) Setup AlwaysOn Availability group with another node, which has SQL Server 2022 (node 1 - SQL v2019, node 2 - SQL v2022)
4) Perform AG failover: DB successfully upgraded to v957

Comment: Dear, SQL Server engineering team, I consider the described case as a bug in SQL Server 2022. Please review it.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue. I had to break the mirroring sessions, dropping the databases that were stuck in recovery and restore from backup. Amazing there isn't more information out there on this error...

Edit:
Steps I took to work around the issue

1. Removed Mirroring session from the mirror side, since the statement cannot be ran against the principal when it is in Recovery Pending status.

```
ALTER DATABASE <dbname> SET PARTNER OFF
```

2. Dropped the principal which was stuck in Recovery Pending

```
DROP DATABASE <dbname>
```

3. Restore the mirror database

```
RESTORE DATABASE <dbname>
```

4. Take a backup of the previous mirror database which is now the active database

```
BACKUP DATABASE <dbname> TO DISK = 'C:\SQLServerBackups\<dbname>.bak';
```

5. Restored the fresh backup to the location of the former principal which was previously dropped.

```
RESTORE DATABASE <dbname> FROM DISK = 'C:\SQLServerBackups\<dbname>.bak' WITH NORECOVERY;
```

6. Re-establish the mirroring session by running the below statement on the former principal server first pointing it at the now active location for the partner_server, and then finalize with running it on the active location with the partner_server being the former principal server.

```
ALTER DATABASE <dbname> SET PARTNER = 'TCP://<partner_server>:<port>'
```

***As of 5/17/2023, Microsoft has acknowledged the bug and said a hot fix will be released in 2022 CU5 or CU6.***

Comment: Thank you for your answer. To make it even more valuable, it would be interesting to provide a few pointers on how to do the three described steps (breaking the mirroring sessions, dropping the databases that were stuck in recovery and restoring from backup) for those who wouldn't know how to do that.